# Why does my repository change after running npm run deploy?

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I have a repository of react code that I deployed to github pages. The code deployed properly and is showing up at the right url, but the repository completely changed. A static folder was created with a bunch of chunk.js files and whatnot. My problem is that I am unsure how to update my code now that it is full of these strange files.

I'm not exactly sure what I should do. A solution I have in mind is just to redeploy to a different branch every time, though I assume that isn't the most elegant way to do things.

I ran `npm run deploy`.

What I expected was that after deploying, my regular repository would show up with all the code I wrote, but there's now a static folder with a bunch of chunk files that I have no idea how to work with. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you follow the steps- https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages

Comment: it should make `gh-pages` branch to add your production project on it

Comment: but anyway you could make discard changes for this commit

Comment: Yes, I followed those steps and that's when I get the problem

Comment: `"deploy": "gh-pages -d build -b master",` just a guess(since you won't show your code), your deploy script looks like this, which is causing problem. `gh-pages` deploy will not go in a folder it will go on branch, by default `gh-pages`, but I guess you have changed it to `master` because you are trying to set-up `gh-pages` for `yourusername.github.io`. In this case your actual development should go on a seperate branch other than master

Answer (score 0):

Follow following steps --

**Step 1**: Add homepage to package.json

```
"homepage": "https://myusername.github.io/my-app",
```

**Step 2**: Install gh-pages and add deploy to scripts in package.json

```
npm install --save gh-pages
```

Add the following scripts in your package.json:

```
 "scripts": {
+   "predeploy": "npm run build",
+   "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
```

**Step 3**: Deploy the site by running npm run deploy

```
npm run deploy
```

**Step 4**: For a project page, ensure your project’s settings use gh-pages
Finally, make sure GitHub Pages option in your GitHub project settings is set to use the gh-pages branch:

**Step 5**: Optionally, configure the domain

```
mywebsite.com
```

reference : https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment **GitHub Pages Section**

Comment: Hi, I should have mentioned that my problem occurs after I've done all the steps you've mentioned.

Comment: This usually works I will try using my code base and let you know